# How can I freely move text and buttons in Android?

Tags: android

How can I freely move text and buttons in Android?
I have only been able to use the gravity options and was wondering how the people on youtube do it so freely.

This is how i add the button:

```
<Button android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:text="Calculate" />
<TextView android:id="@+id/textView1"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_gravity="end"
          android:text="Medium Text"
          android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
```

Comment: What is the Connection between Youtube and Eclipse?

Comment: I have been watching youtube videos and they can freely move text.

Comment: Then show us the video or explain better what this video showed. Because i have no clue what you are talking about! Is it Java, Scala, C, C++, Python, HTML, CSS, Android, SWT, JavaFX, Swing, GWT, GDX?

Comment: Im adding a button, i just want to freely move it,not really a coding problem. When I add a button it just stays in the top left corner and I cannot move it.

Comment: show us the code how you add the Button.

Comment: here is the button added and the text

Comment: <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_gravity="bottom"

        android:text="Calculate" />


    <TextView

        android:id="@+id/textView1"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

Comment: Use a RelativeLayout instead LinearLayout.

Comment: what You mean with "move"? Drag & Drop?